# Count parent comments & replies separately?

Tags: comments

I am trying to find a function, plugin, query - something that will separate the parent comment count from the reply count.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

10 comments total are broken into 3 parent comments and 7 replies. How can I display this at the top of the comment form?

Please & thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

here's a quick and dirty method...

in functions php, we create a callback function for wp_list_comments() which will count our comments:

```
$GLOBALS['parent_comments_count'] = 0;
$GLOBALS['child_comments_count'] = 0;

function count_comments( $comment, $args, $depth ) {
    $GLOBALS['comment'] = $comment;
    if($comment->comment_parent==0):
        $GLOBALS['parent_comments_count']++;
    else:
        $GLOBALS['child_comments_count']++;
    endif;
}
```

then, in our template where it calls wp_list_comments(), we add another with a callback to our count function, then immediately after we can echo our count. then we have the regular wp_list_comments(), which will actually output the comments:

```
wp_list_comments( array( 'callback' => 'count_comments' ) );
echo "parents: ". $GLOBALS['parent_comments_count'];
echo "children: ". $GLOBALS['child_comments_count'];
wp_list_comments();
```

emphasis on 'dirty', I'm sure there's a cleaner way to do this.

Here's another method which uses an additional query. This will get numbers regardless of pagination. We use the `comment_count` variable in `$post` to subtract number of parents from to get number of children.

In functions.php:

```
function c_parent_comment_counter($id){
    global $wpdb;
    $query = "SELECT COUNT(comment_post_id) AS count FROM $wpdb->comments WHERE `comment_approved` = 1 AND `comment_post_ID` = $id AND `comment_parent` = 0";
    $parents = $wpdb->get_row($query);
    return $parents->count;
}
```

In the template:

```
<?php
$number_of_parents = c_parent_comment_counter($post->ID);
$number_of_children = $post->comment_count - $number_of_parents;

echo "parents: ".$number_of_parents;
echo "children: ".$number_of_children;

?>
```

Comment: That is perfect, thank you so much!  I am paginating comments over 100, and it appears to count them separately per page, any way to do a total count regardless of pagination?

Comment: I've edited the answer with another method that should work with paginated comments. It uses an additional SQL query to count just parent comments.

Comment: OH my gosh, Milo.  You have no idea how grateful I am.  THANK you thank you thank you.  I posted over in the WP forums but no reply there - are you a moderator?  Can I link from there to here for others, or copy/paste your fix?